# Can json.Marshal get a field's value from a method?

Tags: go

For example, if we have a struct like this:

```
type device struct {
       Name string
       Online bool
}

func (device) online() bool {
     return true
}
```

I want the value of the field `Online` to come from the method `online()` when I call `json.Mashal` on an instance of this struct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but you'll have to write your own `MarshalJSON` implementation:

```
func (d device) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{
        "Name": d.Name,
        "Online": d.online(),
    })
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/1xFGwsb32rb)